# Unit test for packages outside of django apps

Tags: python, django, tdd

In my Django project I have a few packages/folders that are not applications themselves, but contain code that uses Django models and needs to be covered with tests.
Obiously, when I run 'test nonapppackage.testname' I get:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: App with label xyzutils is
>   missing a models.py module.

What's the best to configure unittest for out-of-app code?

Comment: You can either just a random models.py to your apps, so that you can keep them in your INSTALLED_APPS, or do an ``from xyzutils.tests import *`` in one of your django applications tests module. Are you using django default test runner, or another one?

Comment: Using default test runner, but thinking of test runner that can find tests in other folders.